# Save state for activity indicator in cell

Tags: ios, swift

I have activity indicator in cell. Cells updating with `NSFetchedResultsController`

```
func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {
    switch type {
        case .Update:
           if let _indexPath = indexPath {
            self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([_indexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)
           }
    }
```

My problem that after reload row, activity indicator state set to 0 again and animation looks with jerks.

[image]

Is this possible somehow to save indicator state or don't reload it...

Answer (score 1):

There is no public API to get or set state of `UIActivityIndicatorView` apart from animating or hidden. I think best you can do is to try `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` with some row animation to see if it looks better.

Another wacky thing that comes to mind is, you could take a snapshot of `UIActivityIndicatorView` add it to new cell and fade it out. (perhaps animate even rotation). To make it look smoother. But this is definitely a bad idea and not worth the trouble.